# Passing a variable from an Angular 2 contructor then statement to the template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm having a bit of trouble with a secure login system I'm using.  What I want to do is to check the native storage of the device for an item called 'user', then check the user exists in our database and read in the unique id from it's row in the database to use in a method.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import { NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
import {Events, NavController, NavParams, ModalController, LoadingController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Login} from '../login/login';
import {ChallengePage} from '../challenge/challenge';
import {AddTeamPage} from '../add-team/add-team';
import {EditTeamPage} from '../edit-team/edit-team';
import {Users} from '../../providers/users/users';
import {Teams} from '../../providers/teams/teams';
import {Results} from '../../providers/results/results';
import {Players} from '../../providers/players/players';
import {Packs} from '../../providers/packs/packs';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
})
export class Dashboard {
    _id: string;
    user: any;
    team: any;
    teamExists: boolean;
    gamesPlayed: boolean;
    sample: any;
    strip: any;
    last5: any;
    constructor(
        private nav: NavController,
        public events: Events,
        private _navParams: NavParams,
        private playerService: Players,
        private userService: Users,
        private teamService: Teams,
        private resultService: Results,
        private packService: Packs,
        private modalCtrl: ModalController,
        private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
    ) {
        let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: "Loading..."
        });

        loading.present();
        this.teamExists = false;
        this.gamesPlayed = false;
        var user = {};
        var _id = {};
        //main id
        NativeStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(function (data) {
                user = data;
                console.log("native storage object found");
                userService.accountExists(this.user.email).then((data) => {
                    user = data;
                    if (user) {
                        _id = user['_id'];
                        console.log("user found!", user);
                        console.log("_id for logged in user", _id);
                    } else {
                        console.log("no existing user account found!");
                        nav.setRoot(Login);
                        nav.push(Login);
                        nav.pop();
                    }

                });
            }, function (error) {
                console.error("Error getting user from native storage");
            });
}

addTeam(id) {
    this.nav.push(AddTeamPage, { 'user_id': id });
}
```

EDIT: Added in the template code to call the function.

```
<ion-header class="gradient-dark-up">
    <ion-navbar class="navbar-primary">
        <button ion-button color="main"  icon-left menuToggle>
            <ion-icon class="header-main" name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title><h1 class="header-main">Dashboard</h1></ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only color="primary" *ngIf="!teamExists" (click)="addTeam(_id)"><ion-icon class="header-main" name="add"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

So the id for addTeam should be read in from a button click on the template but when I try to pass the _id in, it's always undefined even though in the constructor when I output the values to console it displays the correct _id.

I think this is just my lack of experience with angular2 tripping me up so if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong feel free to correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the template / component which has `addTeam()` in it?

Comment: I've added in where the code get called from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `this.` to access a property of the current class, don't use `function () {`

```
    NativeStorage.getItem('user')
        .then(function (data) {
```

instead use arrow function

```
    NativeStorage.getItem('user')
        .then((data) => {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, changing over to the arrow function and using this. worked like a charm!